# Phpspreadsheet how to skip first row? (header)

Tags: php, mysql, phpspreadsheet

There is my import code

```
<?php
include("config.php");

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;


if(isset($_POST['import-excel'])){
   $maxsize = 5242880; 
   if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES['file']['name'] != ''){
       $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
       $target_dir = "videos/";
       $target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

       $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
       $extensions_arr = array("mp4","avi","3gp","mov","mpeg");
       
       
      $file = $_FILES["excel-file"]["tmp_name"];
      $Extension = pathinfo($_FILES["excel-file"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      if($Extension == 'xlxs' || $Extension == 'xls' || $Extension == 'csv')
      {
       $obj = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($file);
       $data = $obj->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
      }
      
      
       if( in_array($extension,$extensions_arr) ){
         
          if(($_FILES['file']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["file"]["size"] == 0)) {
             $_SESSION['message'] = "File too large. File must be less than 5MB.";
          }else{
             
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_file)){

                  foreach($data as $row)
                  {
                     
                     $SourceFile = $row['0'];
                     $FileName = $row['1'];
                     $ImageSize = $row['2'];
                     $VideoFrameRate = $row['3'];
                     $CreateDate = $row['4'];
                     $MediaDuration = $row['5'];

                     $author = $_POST["author"];
                     $tags = $_POST["tags"];
                     $genre = $_POST["genre"];
                     $rating = $_POST["rating"];

               
                    $query = "INSERT INTO videos(name,location,author,tags,genre,rating,SourceFile,FileName,ImageSize,VideoFrameRate,CreateDate,MediaDuration) 
                    VALUES('".$name."','".$target_file."','".$author."','".$tags."','".$genre."','".$rating."','".$SourceFile."','".$FileName."','".$ImageSize."','".$VideoFrameRate."','".$CreateDate."','".$MediaDuration."')";

                   mysqli_query($con,$query);
                   $_SESSION['message'] = "Upload successfully.";
                  }
                }
              }

          }else{
          $_SESSION['message'] = "Invalid file extension.";
       }
   }else{
       $_SESSION['message'] = "Please select a file.";
   }
   header('location: index.php');
   exit;
} 
?>
```

Im using theese codes to import csv. to my table

```
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 use PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\IOFactory;
 use PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Spreadsheet;
 use PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Writer\\Xlsx;

 $file = $_FILES["excel-file"]["tmp_name"];
 $Extension = pathinfo($_FILES["excel-file"] 
  ["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 if($Extension == 'xlxs' || $Extension == 'xls' || $Extension == 
 'csv')
       {
        $obj = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($file);
        $data = $obj->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
       }

 foreach($data as $row)
                   {
 
                      $SourceFile = $row['0'];
                      $FileName = $row['1'];
                      $ImageSize = $row['2'];
                      $VideoFrameRate = $row['3'];
                      $CreateDate = $row['4'];
                      $MediaDuration = $row['5'];
                  }
```

[My database table after importing looks like this, it reads and import header from my csv. file which I dont want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tjHs.png)

[My csv. file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ABH.png)

I want to skip header from my csv. file, while importing rest of the rows in my database table.

Comment: If you use `->toArray()` you get a regular array. You are no longer in PhpSpreadsheet realm.

Comment: Hello Álvaro, thank you for your comment. How would you suggest I should proceed ?

Comment: The accepted solution looks fine for this use case, it wouldn't look further.

Comment: Got it! I used array_shift to remove the header ;)                                                                                                                                                                                    
`code` if($Extension == 'xlxs' || $Extension == 'xls' || $Extension == 'csv')
      {
       $obj = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($file);
       $data = $obj->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
       $cut = array_shift($data);
      }